# What is the width of a "column" for a JTextField?

Tags: java, jtextfield, swingx

Per the `JTextField` doc, you can set the width of the field delineated in “columns”, but cannot find a definition for “columns”.

Moreover, doing something like this:

```
new JTextField("abc", 3);
```

Results in a text field of width populated with the string `abc` and then extra whitespace afterwards.

Can someone clarify the the definition of columns as used in the `JTextField` constructor?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a standard `JTextField`, the columns specifies the preferred width of the component as some multiple of `getColumnWidth()`.

The method `getColumnWidth()` defines the width in pixels of each column.  The documentation states: "By default this is defined to be the width of the character 'm' for the font used."

The text field may display at a different size if the layout manager modifies it.

Answer (score 1):

The columns property of JTextField is used to determine the preferred width of the object. If an initial String is provided as in your example `new JTextField("abc", 3);` then the field is painted to match the text size. Otherwise, the columns allow parallel stacking of text within the `JTextField` itself. Therefore, the reason you get whitespace after the `"abc"` in your example is because it defaults to place the string in the first column, then two columns of whitespace.

Comment: OK, but if you simply do:

new JTextField(5);

Then the width of the resulting object accomodates more than 5 characters.  For instance, I can fit about 8 underscore '_' characters in this text field that is noted as 5 columns.  So I'm not clear on *what* column width is.  E.g. what is the pixel width of a column and how does that relate to text that will be placed in it?

Comment: The columns are autosized to fit the necessary information. I'm not sure about Swing's methods, but in FX you can force column width in pixels, percentages of total space, or equal space for all the columns.

Comment: i dont understand what this column bs is. is there a use case where we can see how it affects the ui?

Comment: does it affect when we are using some specific layout?

Comment: This statement is simply false "the columns allow parallel stacking of text within the JTextField itself"  A JTextField is a single line of text.  The "columns" setting influences the preferred width of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the  Enwired's answer. This bugged me for some time.
To further elaborate Enwired's answer, it is the number of m's that the JTextField can display on the screen (panel or window).

Observations

```
new JTextField("mmm", 3);   // this 3 is number of 'm' that we allow to fit in, please note that 'mmm' and 'abc' widths are different even though they are same character count, that is 3
```

For the above code it will display a JTextField with 3 m's width. (we can type more m's on this JTextField, but on the TextField it shows only 3m's)

[image]

If we type "abc" on this, there is still remaining space on the text field where we can accommodate another character like shown below,

[image]

```
new JTextField("mmm", 3);
```

so, the conclusion seems to be it (argument value 3) is not the number of characters that we can fit into JTextField, but the number of 'm' that we can fit in.